# Need to update a list when 2d vector is sorted, prefer to use std::sort

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a 2d array that is based on something stored on a file. I want to sort the 2d array, and update the order of the objects on the file accordingly.

The std::sort function seems to be by far the easiest way to sort the 2d arrays. Is there an easy way to add a couple of lines of code to the sorting algorithm in order to make the same switches in the file that sort() makes to the 2d array?

PS: The file contains several classes that can't easily be sorted directly.

Comment: Try qsort maybe, you can implement compare function there

Comment: cannot you just dump the sorted array into the file? (overwriting what was previously there)

Comment: @Gilad - Looks promising, will try it out. Thanks!

Comment: @vsoftco - I have different classes stored on file. No arrays, unfortunately.

Comment: @Gilad Why `qsort` over `std::sort`?  The `std::sort` has a 3 argument version, where the last argument is the "compare function".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you are right, sort is faster and better then qsort.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Gilad Why not sort the 2d array and recreate the file with the sorted data?